# Normal Covering of a Finite Group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, covering, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $N_1, N_2, \cdots, N_k$ are proper normal subgroups of $G$. The set $\{ N_1, \cdots, N_k\}$ is called a normal cover for $G$, if $G = \cup_{i=1}^kN_i$. I need to the main properties of finite groups with a normal covering. Anybody knows some references on this topic. There are several published papers on covering of groups by subgroups, but I like normal cover. Any comments will be highly appreciated.

Sincerely, 
F Moftakhar

Comment: What kind of properties are you interested in?

Comment: A classification theorem or something like this.

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this. It seems a perfectly reasonable question, if a little vague.

Answer (score 13):

The following paper is relevant:

> *Finite coverings by normal subroups* by Brodie, Chamberlain and Kapp, PAMS 1988.

The main focus is on coverings of infinite groups although their main theorem is still interesting in the finite case.

> **Theorem**. A group
>   has a nontrivial finite
>   covering by normal subgroups if and only if it has a quotient isomorphic to an elementary abelian $p$-group of rank two for some prime $p$.

One of the corollaries to this theorem is also relevant for finite groups:

> **Corollary**. Let $G=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n N_i$ where $N_1,\dots, N_n$
>   form an irredundant covering of $G$ by proper normal subgroups. Then $G/D$ with $D=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n N_i$ is finite and solvable.

This corollary effectively reduces the question of coverings by normal subgroups to the study of solvable groups. The paper can be viewed [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-104-03/S0002-9939-1988-0964841-9/S0002-9939-1988-0964841-9.pdf). If you don't have access email me and I'll send it to you.

Comment: There is a paper by Bhargava which gives a relatively easy proof of this theorem if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know references, but the following might be a starting point for an inductive approach. You might as well assume that each $N_{i}$ is maximal normal in $G.$ Now take a minimal normal subgroup $M$ of $G.$ If $M$ is contained in each $N_{i},$ then you can pass to $G/M$ which still has a normal covering. So you might as well suppose that there is some $i$ with $M \not \leq N_{i}.$ Then $G = M \times N_{i}$ for that $i.$

Later edit: In fact, this reduces the question to the case that $G$ is a direct product of simple groups, some of which may be Abelian, as $G$ embeds into $G/N_{1} \times \ldots \times G/N_{k}$ when $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} N_{i} =1.$

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps not quite on point, but I would like to mention a pretty little fact that is at least related to the question. If $G = \bigcup N_i$, where $N_i \triangleleft G$ and the $N_i$ are nontrivial and proper and have trivial pairwise intersections, then $G$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a complete classification here:

M. Chiodo, *Finitely annihilated groups*, Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. **90**, No. 3, 404-417 (2014).

This also contains a generalisation to arbitrary coverings of groups by proper normal finite-index subgroups; such a group is said to be *Finitely Annihilated* (F-A).

See in particular corollary 5.5: A finite group is F-A if and only if it has non-cyclic abelianisation.

-Maurice

Comment: This Corollary 5.5 follows immediately from the theorem of Brodie, Chamberlain and Kapp, PAMS 1988, see Nick Gill's answer: http://mathoverflow.net/a/185604/24165 .

Comment: Yes, you're right, it does. However, the preceding result in that paper requires a little more work, though still uses the Brodie-Chamberlain-Kapp result.

Proposition 5.4. Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with only finitely many distinct finite simple quotients. Then $G$ is F-A if and only if $G^{ab}$ is noncyclic.